# About Metro GUI in desktop application

Tags: java, swing, microsoft-metro, awt, look-and-feel

I am making a software that will support multiple features simultaneously. I know the logic, and I have developed the features to support.

I want my project to have a look similar to Metro GUI of Windows 8. It need not to be specifically Metro, but similar.

I know about all the layouts in standard Swing library. Currently I am using `GroupLayout` though. How should I proceed, any ideas? Because the UI seems dull and I don't want to use 3rd party APIs either.
Any suggestions?

Comment: OK I don't get it.  What is it about the look of a Metro app. that comes down to layouts, as opposed to see the [pluggable **look** and feel](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/look-and-feel/info)?  Can you post some images or links to them?  Preferably for the same app. on Windows 7 *and* Metro.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any images, as I dumped my GUI. I was reconstructing it. And metro UI consists of Tiles which can be dragged to relocate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would use `GridBagLayout`, simply because it would allow you to supply better weighted constraints to each "group", but even that might not be entirely suitable.

I would also take a look for the Metro UX guidelines for more ideas

These might be helpful

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx#tile_design_philosophy
- http://blendinsider.com/technical/ux-guidelines-for-metro-style-app-development-2011-10-21/ (look for the section on tiles)

Comment: From the MSDN article *"Simple, clean, elegantly designed tiles will be more successful than those that scream for attention like a petulant child."*.  Classic.  :)

Comment: Don't you think that GroupLayout is more versatile than GridBagLayout. And do you have any ideas on how to make Panels or any internal components of a Frame, draggable. And don't mention JInternalFrames. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt No actually.  `GridLayout` will require that each panel be the same size will be allocated a equal percentage of the available.  `GridBagLayout` will allow you to have panels that expand columns/rows, have different weights (height/width) and generally provide you a far more flexible layout solution.  Personally, if you're not going to write your own, this is the next best solution - IMHO