# Is there a way to get a look and feel of windows 8 metro on java desktop application?

Tags: java, windows-8, look-and-feel

I am really struggling to find a good answer to this question, as stated in the Title. I am currently developing an application that will be desktop only with no CSS or any internet parts at all. I would like it to look like the metro look of Windows 8. I'm not talking about the layout but the look and feel. I would especially like the buttons that are square and not rounded but all the other flat square look and feel too. The following link is the opposite of what I'm looking for, as a reference.

[About Metro GUI in desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589714/about-metro-gui-in-desktop-application)

This read was at least a little closer to a discussion on native look and feel and java. However it doesn't actually give any concrete ways to get for instance a square flat button:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/226521/why-is-it-hard-to-make-a-java-program-appear-native

Currently I am using Eclipse but I'm not stuck on using that necessarily, but it wold be easiest. I have been looking into JavaFx but it doesn't seem to have square buttons or a metro feel at all from what I've read but maybe I'm missing something. Can any one point me in a good direction on how to make the look and feel simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigate the [JMetro](https://pixelduke.wordpress.com/category/metro/) style for JavaFX and see if it fits what you need.  JMetro is part of the [jfxtras](http://jfxtras.org/) third party supplemental library for JavaFX.  Code for existing JMetro styles in the [jfxtras-styles](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-styles) project.

[image: JMetro buttons]

[image: jmetro checkboxes]

Do not expect a polished fully complete theme that integrates seamlessly with the OS style (so it won't be for everybody).  Nor is it a library officially supported by Oracle (it's a third party code donation thing).   As a comparative point, support for [a JavaFX Aqua look and feel for OS X](http://aquafx-project.com/documentation.html) is currently more complete than JMetro is for the Windows Metro UI.  The AquaFX look and feel looks and acts almost exactly like the native OS X 10.9 look and feel to my eyes.

If you come with the right expectations, then you may find the JMetro look and feel acceptable for your project.  You can find out more info by contacting [Pedro Duque Vieira](https://pixelduke.wordpress.com/about/) who created the JMetro styles.

Comment: I think the best part of this answer is to come with the right expectations. I am a mac person but the client is a windows person, so JMetro it is. I have looked at this a little but the learning curve for all of this GUI seems steep. Thank you.