# Using Java Look and Feel for new interface

Tags: java, user-interface, look-and-feel

I want to make my **java user interface** **looks like the metro interface in windows 8**.

Then i think I will using the look and feel to make it. But it just offers limited interfaces. so I want to make it by myself, but I don't how; So I appreciate for you guys who want to help me.

For the image references is such as shown in the images linked below.

[[KGB Style]](http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/062/b/4/windows_ui_concept__explorer_3_by_kgbstyle-d4rn1y6.jpg)

[[Skype]](http://redsgned.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/skype.jpg)

At least i can copy the window interface of those styles aswell.
That is my interface expectation, so I hope of your help guys. Thanks

Comment: I think you should look into Java FX. Last time I checked Java did not have any major UI frameworks.

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110716/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-look-and-feel-of-windows-8-metro-on-java-desktop-applica might be already what you want.

Comment: @npinti : what's different? i have no idea about javaFX

Comment: @SubOptimal : i think that's using javaFX too, isn't?

Comment: Java FX is similar to C#'s WPF, it allows for more freedom when compared to Swing. The comment provided by @SubOptimal shows a Java FX approach to the Windows 8 Metro UI.

Comment: can Java FX changes the whole of window interface such as close button, minimaze, etc.

Comment: And how about Synth Look and Feel, do you know it? i ever read that is also could change the styles

Comment: @MuhammadAlFatih Have a look at the side of [Pedro Duque Vieira](https://pixelduke.wordpress.com/category/metro/) who created the JMetro styles. His site was also linked on the post in my first comment.